# Insert Json into Hbase as JSON - Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, hbase

I would like to insert a json object into a Hbase cellusing scala, presently i'm able to insert values using the below code but would like to know how i may be able to insert the entire Json object into a Hbase cell.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.toBytes
val hTable:HTable = new HTable(configuration, "tablename")
val p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("row1"))
p.add(Bytes.toBytes("info"),Bytes.toBytes("firstname)",Bytes.toBytes("Jim"))
hTable.put(p)
hTable.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can encode your json object as a string. then encode this string as byte array. then put this byte array in Hbase. pseudo code will be like this:

```
json = createYourJson()
jsonString = json.toString
jsonBytyes = Bytes.toBytes(jsonString)
put.add(yourColumnFamily, yourQualifier, jsonBytes)
```

and when loading the value from hbase you have to reverse this order. Pseudo code will be like this:

```
jsonBytes = hbase.get(table, columnFamily, qualifier)
jsonString = Bytes.toString(jsonBytes)
json = Json.parse(jsonString)
```

Comment: im getting a overload method error as cannot be applied to (Array[Byte]), below is the code 

  
  p.add(Bytes.toBytes("columnfamily"),Bytes.toBytes("qualifier)",Bytes.toBytes("jsonBytes"))

     hTable.put(m)

Comment: yes, you should add the column family and the qualifier. I edited my answer.

Comment: yea tried as below 

m.add(Bytes,toBytes("columnfamily"),Bytes.toBytes("qualifier"),Bytes.toBytes(jsonBytes))  - same issue

Comment: Bytes,toBytes("columnfamily") this is comma?

Comment: sorry , keyboard issue . this fixed it . im able to now insert but it is not being inserted as a json format ?

Comment: You have to parse it again to json after loading it. I edited my answer.